# How to link script and connect socket.io on production server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new on all related JavaScript programmimg and I have an application using nodejs and socket.io perfectly working on local (Mac). However I can't figure out how to link the socket.io script and not sure how to connect to socket.io from app once in my running server (Hostgator dedicated running CentOS) where I'm also using claudflare.

I've tried several combinations:

**index.php**

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 //or also <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 //console output is: Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://www.example.com/socket.io/socket.io.js”.

 <script src="my_ip_number/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 //console output is: Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://www.example.com/my_ip_number/socket.io/socket.io.js”.

<script src="my_ip_number:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 //console output is: Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://www.example.com/my_ip_number:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js”.

//the most odd one
<script src="https://my_ip_number/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 //console output is: Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://0.0.0/my_ip_number/socket.io/socket.io.js”.
```

**app.js (client)**

```
var socket = io.connect('my_ip_number:8080', { query: 'userid='+userOnline});
```

**EDITED**

I can get the script link working if I link to the CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
```

That corresponds to the server version as well. In this case I'll get the following error on console:

```
client connect_error:  Error: xhr poll error
Stack trace:
r.prototype.onError@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js:2:7328
o.prototype.doPoll/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js:2:1979
r.prototype.emit@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js:1:12370
i.prototype.onError@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js:2:3683
i.prototype.create/n.onreadystatechange/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js:2:3309
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;

http.listen(8080, function(){
console.log('listening');
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you get any solution for your problem, please share!

Comment: No... it's dark magic still for me, and couldn't really get help of anybody. Gave it up for now and working on http to comeback to the problem later. If I have a solution will surely share.